# Shopify regular expressions for checkout process

Tags: regex, shopify, query-string

I am working with the Google Ads team in my company on a Shopify store and they asked me for some regular expressions for the several steps of the checkout process. I created them and everything was running fine, until the guys noticed that sometimes Analytics added a `_ga` paremeter to the URL query parameters.

My original expressions are:

**1. When in cart - no problem here**

```regex
\/cart
```

**2. First step of checkout - Contact Information - In several lines for easier reading**

```regex
(
    \/([0-9]*)\/checkouts\/([a-z0-9\-]*)$
    |
    \/([0-9]*)\/checkouts\/([a-z0-9\-]*)\?step=contact_information
)
```

In this part I added the `step=contact_information` as an OR option. It isn't normally there except for when you go back to contact information it is added to the URL as step. I know this is not the ideal way, but I am far from fluent in regex.

**3. Shipping information**

```regex
(
    \/([0-9]*)\/checkouts\/([a-z0-9\-]*)\?step=shipping_method
    |
    \/([0-9]*)\/checkouts\/([a-z0-9\-]*)?(.*)&step=shipping_method
)
```

In this part it always has `step=shipping_method` but it can also have `previous_step=contact_information`. This is also not ideal, but I am not sure how to do it.

**4. Payment information**

```regex
(
    \/([0-9]*)\/checkouts\/([a-z0-9\-]*)\?step=payment_method
    |
    \/([0-9]*)\/checkouts\/([a-z0-9\-]*)?(.*)&step=payment_method
)
```

The same as step 3, in this case it always has `step=payment_method` but it can also have `previous_step=shipping_method`. As points 2 and 3, not ideal.

**5. Processing - this part works fine, because I am not interested in the query parameters**

```regex
\/([0-9]*)\/checkouts\/([a-z0-9\-]*)\/processing
```

**6. Thank you page - this also works fine, because I am not interested in the query parameters**

```regex
\/([0-9]*)\/checkouts\/([a-z0-9\-]*)\/thank_you
```

**Issue with _ga parameter**

Those regular expressions work fine with the regular URLs, but when I add the `_ga` parameter to the URL they don't match. I think there was a way to match query parameters, but I am not sure how to match certain and exclude others.

The `_ga` parameter normally persists on the next steps

The list of all the possible matches for points 2., 3. and 4.:

**Contact information without and with _ga**

```
/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82
/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82?step=contact_information

/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82?_ga=2.150710640.738515769.1576779089-71346777.1571176760%26_gac%3D1.16451458.1576260301.EAIaIQobChMI9v2c5Zqz5gIVr__jBx1VAgxPEAAYBCAAEgLccPD_BwE&locale=es
/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82?_ga=2.150710640.738515769.1576779089-71346777.1571176760%26_gac%3D1.16451458.1576260301.EAIaIQobChMI9v2c5Zqz5gIVr__jBx1VAgxPEAAYBCAAEgLccPD_BwE&locale=es&step=contact_information
```

**Shipping method without and with _ga**

```
/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82?step=shipping_method
/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82?step=shipping_method&previous_step=contact_information

/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82?_ga=2.150710640.738515769.1576779089-71346777.1571176760%26_gac%3D1.16451458.1576260301.EAIaIQobChMI9v2c5Zqz5gIVr__jBx1VAgxPEAAYBCAAEgLccPD_BwE&locale=es&step=shipping_method
/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82?_ga=2.150710640.738515769.1576779089-71346777.1571176760%26_gac%3D1.16451458.1576260301.EAIaIQobChMI9v2c5Zqz5gIVr__jBx1VAgxPEAAYBCAAEgLccPD_BwE&locale=es&step=shipping_method&previous_step=contact_information
```

**Payment method without and with _ga**

```
/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82?step=payment_method
/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82?step=payment_method&previous_step=shipping_method

/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82?_ga=2.150710640.738515769.1576779089-71346777.1571176760%26_gac%3D1.16451458.1576260301.EAIaIQobChMI9v2c5Zqz5gIVr__jBx1VAgxPEAAYBCAAEgLccPD_BwE&locale=es&step=payment_method
/25931284564/checkouts/df24e48ecc81f767583c4a26680bcb82?_ga=2.150710640.738515769.1576779089-71346777.1571176760%26_gac%3D1.16451458.1576260301.EAIaIQobChMI9v2c5Zqz5gIVr__jBx1VAgxPEAAYBCAAEgLccPD_BwE&locale=es&step=payment_method&previous_step=shipping_method
```

Any ideas how I could solve this? I am pretty sure it's simple, but my brain just doesn't get around more complex regular expressions :)

**UPDATE**

Just to clear this up a bit more, what I need to achieve with the regular expressions is to identify specifically the step of the funnel.

The Google Ads guys from my team are creating a funnel in Analytics and they add the corresponding steps from the checkout as stages of the funnel.

So basically I just need my regexes to be able to work with or without the `_ga` query, BUT always detecting a specific step.

**UPDATE 2**

I added all the possible matches. I need to be able to identify the specific step through the regular expression. So basically I need one regular expression for contact information, one for shipping method and one for payment method, each identifying only the specific step with or without `_ga` in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I believe for the checkout url you can simply use this regex:

```
/([0-9]+)/checkouts/([a-z0-9-]+)(?:.*step=([a-z0-9_-]+))?
```

no matter if the url is with/without `_ga` parameter.
Basically it will provide you three groups in a match, the third group will contain `step` parameter value, e.g.: `contact_information`

Example:
https://regex101.com/r/C1GuDY/1

Comment: No, because that would match steps 2, 3 and 4 and I need to separate them, because the Google Ads theme is using a funnel and they are separating each step. The query parameters serve to distinguish the specific step. If you check, the base URL for the three is the same, what changes are the query parameters.

Comment: this regular expression still matches steps 2, 3 and 4. I need separate regular expressions to match the specific steps. With this one, both steps 2, 3 and 4 are matched all the time. That's why I am specifically including the step value, such as `contact_information`, `shipping_method` and `payment_method`.

Comment: I updated my question, adding some more information on what I need.

Comment: @MihailMinkov, if you open up the link in my answer, you'll see that regex `Group 3` will have the `step` value. So based on this you can distinguish the urls. And you need only one regex to cover all these cases.

Comment: I am not sure if I explained myself correctly, I have 3 separate matches and this regular expression matches all of them. I need it to match only one of 3. I'll update my question with all the different possibilities.

Comment: Done @KirilPolishchuk, I updated my question with all the necessary separate matches.

Comment: @KirilPolishchuk Basically something like: in the first one (contact_information) exclude either `shipping_method` or `payment_method`, in the second (shipping method) exclude either `contact_information` or `payment_method` and in the third (payment method) exclude either `shipping_method` or `contact_information`.

Comment: @KirilPolishchuk any recommendations on how to fix that part? I am sure with what you already created it's just adding the variatons for each case.